# Hive for complex nested Json

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have an original input json snippet ('/home/user/testsample.json') -

```
{"key": "somehashvalue","columns": [["Event:2014-03-26 00\\:29\\:13+0200:json","{\"user\":{\"credType\":\"ADDRESS\",\"credValue\":\"01:AA:A4:G1:HH:UU\",\"cAgent\":null,\"cType\":\"ACE\"},\"timestamp\":1395786553,\"sessionId\":1395785353,\"className\":\"Event\",\"subtype\":\"CURRENTLYACTIVE\",\"vType\":\"TEST\",\"vId\":1235080,\"eType\":\"CURRENTLYACTIVE\",\"eData\":\"1\"}",1395786553381001],["Event:2014-03-26 00\\:29\\:13+0200:","",1395786553381001]]}
```

I tried to use Json serde s to parse the above json to my hive columns. However, 1395786553381001 above is not present in a format which SerDe can map to a Hive column i.e this value is present without a Key (since Hive understands Json columns/values present after :)

So instead I took the Array type approach and created a table -

```
CREATE TABLE mytesttable (
  key string, 
  columns array < array< string > >
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/user/testsample.json'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytesttable;
```

select columns[0][1] from mytesttable;
gives -

```
{"user":{"credType":"ADDRESS","credValue":"01:AA:A4:G1:HH:UU","cAgent":null,"cType":"ACE"},"timestamp":1395786553,"sessionId":1395785353,"className":"Event","subtype":"CURRENTLYACTIVE","vType":"TEST","vId":1235080,"eType":"CURRENTLYACTIVE","eData":"1"}
```

The above appears clean, but then I also need columns[*][2] i.e in a Json hive column for further transformations.

I wrote a regex hive query to cleanse the original Json present in `'/home/user/testsample.json'` (assume it is present in a table tablewithinputjson)

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(ij.columna, '["][{]', '{'),'[}]["]', '}'), '\\\\', '') AS columna
FROM tablewithinputjson ij;
```

The above query returns -

```
{"key": "somehashvalue","columns": [["Event:2014-03-26 00:29:13+0200:json",{"user":{"credType":"ADDRESS","credValue":"01:AA:A4:G1:HH:UU","cAgent":null,"cType":"ACE"},"timestamp":1395786553,"sessionId":1395785353,"className":"Event","subtype":"CURRENTLYACTIVE","vType":"TEST","vId":1235080,"eType":"CURRENTLYACTIVE","eData":"1"},1395786553381001],["Event:2014-03-26 00:29:13+0200:","",1395786553381001]]}
```

But here again, 1395786553381001 cannot be mapped to a hive column since it appears after , and not after : or more specifically this value is present without a key.
(I could add "test": before 1395786553381001 , but I do not want to customize the input data - since a) Too much customization is something I am not comfortable with b) does not seem to be a good solution c) it would unnecessary waste my hadoop cluster space and time)

Not to confuse any further, I am not able to come up with a Hive table format that fully parses and maps all the fields in the original Json snippet. 
Any suggestions are welcome. Please let me know If it seems too confusing.

Answer (score 3):

posting End-to-End solution. Step by step procedure to convert JSON to hive table:

step 1)  install maven if not there already

`>$ sudo apt-get install maven`

step 2) install git if not there already

`>sudo git clone https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde.git`

step 3) go into the $HOME/HIVE-JSON_Serde folder

step 4) build the serde package

`>sudo mvn -Pcdh5 clean package`

step 5) The serde file will be in 
   **$HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

step 6) Add serde as dependency jar in hive

```
 hive> ADD JAR $HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7- SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

step 7) create json file in $HOME/books.json (Example)

```
{"value": [{"id": "1","bookname": "A","properties": {"subscription": "1year","unit": "3"}},{"id": "2","bookname":"B","properties":{"subscription": "2years","unit": "5"}}]}
```

step 8) create tmp1 table in hive

```
 hive>CREATE TABLE tmp1 (
      value ARRAY<struct<id:string,bookname:string,properties:struct<subscription:string,unit:string>>>   
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
    'mapping.value' = 'value'   
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

step 9) load the data from json to tmp1 table

```
>LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '$HOME/books.json' INTO TABLE tmp1;
```

step 10) create a tmp2 table to do explode operation form tmp1, this intermediate step is to break multi level json structure into multiple rows 
Note: if your JSON structure is simple and single level , avoid this step

```
hive>create table tmp2 as 
 SELECT *
 FROM tmp1
 LATERAL VIEW explode(value) itemTable AS items;
```

step 11) create hive table and load the values from tmp2 table

```
hive>create table books as 
select value[0].id as id, value[0].bookname as name, value[0].properties.subscription as subscription, value[0].properties.unit as unit from tmp2;
```

step 12) drop tmp tables

```
hive>drop table tmp1;
hive>drop table tmp2;
```

step 13) test the hive table

```
hive>select * from books;
```

output:

id name subscription unit

1 B 1year 3

2 B 2years 5

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to run it for HDP 2.5.6?