# Create table and query json data using Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to query JSON data of format using Amazon Athena:

```
[{"id":"0581b7c92be",
  "key":"0581b7c92be",
  "value":{"rev":"1-ceeeecaa040"},
  "doc":{"_id":"0581b7c92be497d19e5ab51e577ada12","_rev":"1ceeeecaa04","node":"belt","DeviceId":"C001"}},
 {"id":"0581b7c92be49",
  "key":"0581b7c92be497d19e5",
  "value":{"rev":"1-ceeeecaa04031842d3ca"},
  "doc":{"_id":"0581b7c92be497","_rev":"1ceeeecaa040318","node":"belt","DeviceId":"C001"}
 }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Athena DDL is based on Hive, so u will want each json object in your array to be in a separate line:

```
{"id": "0581b7c92be", "key": "0581b7c92be", "value": {"rev": "1-ceeeecaa040"}, "doc": {"_id": "0581b7c92be497d19e5ab51e577ada12", "_rev": "1ceeeecaa04", "node": "belt", "DeviceId": "C001"} }
{"id": "0581b7c92be49", "key": "0581b7c92be497d19e5", "value": {"rev": "1-ceeeecaa04031842d3ca"}, "doc": {"_id": "0581b7c92be497", "_rev": "1ceeeecaa040318", "node": "belt", "DeviceId": "C001"} }
```

You might have problems with the nested fields ("value","doc"), so if you can flatten the jsons you will have it easier. (see for example: [Hive for complex nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220759/hive-for-complex-nested-json))

Comment: i want how to create table and select operation to  query multiple lines of data.

Comment: i want how to create table and select operation to  query multiple lines of data.ex:[{
 "_id": "0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe",
 "_rev": "1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38",
 "deviceId": "BELT001",
 "locationId": "LID001",
 "SuperviceId": "SID001"
}, {
 "_id": "0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe",
 "_rev": "1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38",
 "deviceId": "BELT001",
 "locationId": "LID001",
 "SuperviceId": "SID001"
}]

Comment: What I'm saying is that before I can help you, please check If you can "explode" your json array into lines of separate json objects. convert your example to:

Comment: {"_id": "0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe", "_rev": "1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38", "deviceId": "BELT001", "locationId": "LID001", "SuperviceId": "SID001"}
{"_id": "0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe", "_rev": "1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38", "deviceId": "BELT001", "locationId": "LID001", "SuperviceId": "SID001"}

Comment: Thanks for solution.I am able to query data from athena